# Adding numbers inside array of arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here I'm trying to add number of array separately, but I'm not able to achieve the expected output. If I want to add total I would do `flatMap` and add them togeather. But I want add them separately for each array.

Below is the snippet for what I have tried

```js
const data = [{
    "itemDetails": [{
      "sizeOfBag": 1,
      "numberOfBags": 1,
      "quantityInBag": 1.0
    }]
  },
  {

    "itemDetails": [{
        "sizeOfBag": 1,
        "numberOfBags": 1,
        "quantityInBag": 1.0
      },
      {
        "sizeOfBag": 10,
        "numberOfBags": 1,
        "quantityInBag": 1.0
      }
    ],

  }
]
const newData = data.map(f => f.itemDetails);
console.log(newData);

for (let i = 0; i <= newData.length; i++) {
  const addData = newData.reduce((acc, newData) => acc + newData[i].sizeOfBag, 0);
}
console.log(addData);
```

Expected Output: `[1,11]`

Comment: @hev1 Updated with expected output

Comment: You have the `for` loop syntax wrong, it should be `;` between the parts of the header, not `,`.

Comment: @Barmar Updated, still getting some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map and reduce.

```
const res = newData.map(arr=>arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr.sizeOfBag,0));
```

Your attempt with the for loop is close, but you are looping past the last index and mixing up your index with property names.

```
for (let i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
  newData[i] = newData[i].reduce((acc, newData) => acc + newData.sizeOfBag, 0);
}
```

Comment: One doubt here. We are using `map` twice, so why can't we use `flatMap` ?

Comment: We are only using map once. The result is a one dimensional array so there is no need to flatten it.

Comment: is it possible to get the output as same `[{"itemDetails": [{'totalSizeOfBag': 0}]},{"itemDetails": [{'totalSizeOfBag': 11}]}]`

Comment: I think that merits a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `reduce` on the nested arrays, not the top-level `newData` array. You can combine all these calls using `map` to get an array of the results.

```js
const data = [{
    "itemDetails": [{
      "sizeOfBag": 1,
      "numberOfBags": 1,
      "quantityInBag": 1.0
    }]
  },
  {

    "itemDetails": [{
        "sizeOfBag": 1,
        "numberOfBags": 1,
        "quantityInBag": 1.0
      },
      {
        "sizeOfBag": 10,
        "numberOfBags": 1,
        "quantityInBag": 1.0
      }
    ],

  }
]
const newData = data.map(f => f.itemDetails);
console.log(newData);

const addData = newData.map(d => d.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x.sizeOfBag, 0));

console.log(addData);
```

Comment: is it possible to get the output as same `[{"itemDetails": [{'totalSizeOfBag': 0}]},{"itemDetails": [{'totalSizeOfBag': 11}]}]`

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this, run the reduce function inside your map:

```
data.map(f => f.itemDetails.reduce((acc, i) => acc + i.sizeOfBag, 0));
```

Comment: is it possible to get the output as same `[{"itemDetails": [{'totalSizeOfBag': 0}]},{"itemDetails": [{'totalSizeOfBag': 11}]}]`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But that's not what you said you wanted as expected output.

Comment: Use `{totalSizeOfBag: 0}` as the 2nd argument to `reduce`, and `(acc.totalSizeOfBag += i.sizeOfBag, acc)` as the body of the arrow function.